How is the expression for work in this problem derived?

In this solution to the problem I found, the work expression comes out to be the force times $d$, the difference in distances from the collar to the force origin at positions A an B. I can't for the life of me figure out how this is derived.
It seems as simple as the work integral, integral(F dot dr), but dr refers to the path the particle follows, not the position vector from the particle to the force origin, so I don't understand how it works out this way.
My professor is unable to explain this "shortcut" to me as he does these problems with very tedious brute-force geometry and calculus that doesn't derive this, and which I would prefer not to do on an exam if possible. His answer was the same as the one acquired from the method here. I've tried to follow online resources for work but they don't ever seem to deal with cases of forces which vary in direction throughout the trajectory and deal with extremely simple cases.
Any help at all is appreciated

When doing work calculations, we only care about the component of motion in the direction of the force. In this case, we care about how much the distance towards the pulleys changes, since that is the direction in which the force is applied at all times, even as that direction changes with the motion of the collar.
If we start a distance $d_i$ from the pulleys and end up a distance $d_f$ away from them, then we have traveled a total distance $d_i-d_f$ towards the pulleys. Since motion towards the pulleys is always parallel to the applied force, the total work done is simply $F(d_i-d_f)$.
You can imagine the collar taking infinitesimal steps along the circular rod, and after each step, take the component of its motion that points towards the pulleys. Since we get $d_i-d_f$ closer to the pulleys over the entire trajectory, those components pointing towards the pulleys have to have added up to $d_i-d_f$.
Hope this helps.

Thank you! This makes sense now, that we care about the distance traveled towards the source of the force, the difference of the distances!

You're welcome, but to be clear, in general, we care not about the distance traveled toward the source of the force, but the distance travelled parallel to the force vector. Those just happen to be the same thing in this problem, if you consider the "source" to be the pulleys (which may or may not make sense). This is because the work expression $dW=\textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r}$ contains a dot product, which extracts the parallel components of the force and displacement.

System:
collar.
External forces acting on the system:

Gravitation force $mg$ acting vertically downwards;
Normal force $N$;
String-exerted force of $40\,\rm N$.

Work done on the system:

By the gravitational force: $-mgh$, where $h$ is the vertical height raised by the collar.
By the normal force: zero, as the motion of the collar is always at right angles to this force.
By the $40\,\rm N$ force: This is the interesting part of the problem and possibly is the source of some confusion as to the part played by the pulley.
All the pulley does is change the direction of the force acting on the collar in such a way that the displacement of the force is always in the same direction as the force.
This means that the work done on the collar due to that force is $40\,\mathrm{N} \times d$, where $d$ is the distance the cord moves past the pulley.

The sum of the total work done by the external forces is equal to the change in the kinetic energy of the collar.

It just so happens that nothing else except the collar is moving in this system. This means that all the energy that is provided by the pulling 40N force is going to go into the kinetic energy and potential energy of the collar, by conservation of energy.
Consider from the PoV of, say, the hand pulling in a straight line on the cord (from after the pulleys). That is an input of energy, by the definition of work done, exactly equal to the constant force multiplied by the distance of cord retracted.
$$W=KE+GPE\qquad\implies\qquad KE=F\Delta d-GPE$$
